# Why am i getting a parse error and how can i solve this error in haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, haskell-stack, ghci, args

I'm new to Haskell and while reading real-world Haskell I came across a problem:

Q) Using the command framework from the earlier section “A Simple Command-Line Framework” on page 71, write a program that prints the first word of each line of its input.

The command framework is:

```
-- file: ch04/InteractWith.hs
-- Save this in a source file, e.g., Interact.hs

import System.Environment (getArgs)

interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do
  input <- readFile inputFile
  writeFile outputFile (function input)

main = mainWith myFunction
  where mainWith function = do
      args <- getArgs
      case args of
        [input,output] -> interactWith function input output
        _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"
-- replace "id" with the name of our function below
myFunction = id
```

My solution to the problem is:

```
-- file: ch04/InteractWith.hs
-- Save this in a source file, e.g., Interact.hs

import System.Environment (getArgs)

interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do
  input <- readFile inputFile
  writeFile outputFile (function input)

main = mainWith myFunction
  where mainWith function = do
      args <- getArgs
      case args of
        [input,output] -> interactWith function input output
        _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"
-- replace "id" with the name of our function below
myFunction = concat (map (++"\n") (map head (map words (lines input))))
```

As per instructions, whenever I try to compile this program using `ghc --make filename` I get a parse error i.e.

```
error: parse error on input ‘args’
   |
36 |       args <- getArgs
   |       ^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation is off.

Haskell is sensitive to whitespace. In particular, among other things, the "inside" of a "block" must generally be indented farther to the right than the beginning of that block. In your case this means that the inside of `do` must be indented to the right of `mainWith` on the preceding line.

Try this:

```
main = mainWith myFunction
  where mainWith function = do
          args <- getArgs
          case args of
            [input,output] -> interactWith function input output
            _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"
```

Comment: It solved the first error but now it gives me a new one.

Comment: Well, if you have a different question, feel free to post it to StackOverflow. I'm sure somebody will be able to answer.

Comment: Couldn't match expected type ‘String -> String’
          with actual type ‘[Char]’
In the first argument of ‘mainWith’, namely ‘myFunction’
  In the expression: mainWith myFunction
  In an equation for ‘main’:
      main
        = mainWith myFunction
        where
            mainWith function
              = do args <- getArgs
|
34 | main = mainWith myFunction
|
Variable not in scope: input :: String
 |
41 | myFunction = concat (map (++"\n") (map head (map words (lines input))))

Comment: Sorry, something weird is happening with my internet, the other comment wasn't being posted. Also sorry for the horrible formatting